# How can I have a C++ set with more than 1 data type?

Tags: c++, c++11, set

Trying to learn C++ coming from Python, and in python a set can have multiple types. How do I do this in C++? I'm specifically trying to have a set with both integers and strings. For example:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    set<int, string> s;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert("string");
    
}
```

Comment: `set<variant<int,string>>`?

Comment: @EOF I was about writing the same, I am just not sure  ATM, if `std::variant` fulfills all the requirements needed for `std::set`.

Comment: I did see that but it's a C++17 feature. Is there an equivalent for C++11?

Comment: There is boost.variant. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96064192a3da7e34

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure either, but honestly I'm even less sure about when this would ever be necessary or even useful at all.

Comment: Can't you have two distinct sets? Just by the type of a key you know which set it should belong to.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to C++11?

Comment: @bipll I don't think that will work for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to calculate first and follow sets so the set would need to contain 2 different structs I created, "ID" and "EPSILON"

Comment: If you want to do this kind of thing, then C++ is not the language you want. Different languages make different design trade-offs for good reasons, and you are wise not to fight them on such a fundamental level.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *"Why restrict yourself to C++11?"* -Because some of us don't get to choose our toolchain and/or technology stack, and have to fight tooth and nail with development managers to get any traction in advancement whatsoever. I'm in a similar boat. I would *dearly* love to use C++17  (also for `std::variant`, coincidentally), but my company is locked into VS2015 (which was a miracle in itself to get to), and C++14 (mostly) is the best I can do. Some people are even more crippled (and I feel their pain).

Comment: @WhozCraig Since OP is just learning, I expected them to have the privilege of using any shiny up-to-date compilers they want. :)

Comment: According to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sz33Gj), both gcc and clang seem to think `std::variant<int, std::string>` is OK to have in a `std::set`, so my original proposal should work. I have to admit I can't see any reason why you would prefer it to something like `std::pair<std::set<int>, std::set<string>>` though.

Comment: C++ is not like Python, you should un-learn some stuff. In c++ you try to make sure your code is correct at compile time. You use various code constructs that cause compile error s if you try to do something illegal which can cause UB (Undefined Behaviour) or break your application logic... But you may work in C++ almost like in Python, besides std::variant, there is std::any  (boost has it either) which will accept anything you assign to it.

Comment: This feels like an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem, if you provide more context, it would help us give better suggestions. Its seems unlikely that you actually need an (ordered) set of multiple types. What does it mean to order ints and strings?.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple types of elements in a container is called a *heterogenous container*.

C++ supports this from C++17 using [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) which can hold any type, or [as EOF said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407808/how-can-i-have-a-c-set-with-more-than-1-data-type#comment113890078_64407808) using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) when you want to define the set of possible types yourself.

Here is a demo of `std::any` using [std::any_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast):

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::any> any_list;

    int myInt = 1;
    std::string myString("I'm a string");

    using MapType = std::map<std::list<int>, std::string>;
    MapType myMap;

    struct CustomType {
        void* pointer;
    };

    any_list.emplace_back(std::any());
    any_list.emplace_back(myInt);
    any_list.emplace_back(myString);
    any_list.emplace_back(myMap);
    any_list.emplace_back(CustomType());

    // To show the awesome power of std::any we add
    // the list as an element of itself:
    any_list.emplace_back(any_list);

    for(auto& element: any_list) {
        if(!element.has_value()) {
            std::cout << "Element does not hold a value" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (int* someInt = std::any_cast<int>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "Element is int: " << *someInt << '\n';
        } else if (std::string* s = std::any_cast<std::string>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "Element is a std::string: " << *s << '\n';
        } else if (std::any_cast<MapType>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "Element is of type MapType\n";
        } else if (std::any_cast<CustomType>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "Element is of type CustomType\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Element is of unknown but very powerful type\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This yields output:

```
Element does not hold a value
Element is int: 1
Element is a std::string: I'm a string
Element is of type MapType
Element is of type CustomType
Element is of unknown but very powerful type
```

The pre-C++17 method of doing this is obviously a `struct` with manual type info and `void*`.

Note that I used `std::list` instead of `std::set` because `std::any` does not have `operator<` defined by default. This could be solved by defining your own comparison predicate.

My personal opinion is that usually when you think you want to use a heterogenous container it's worth re-evaluating your design and stick to normal homogenous containers, but it's there if you need it :-)